# Open Weather API use JSON data

Tags: api, openweathermap

```
var weather;
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("wellco");
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
canvas.width  = 1224;
canvas.height = 768;
canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

 //the part where things go wrong begins
data = $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=c5959a33372923c74fccc1d07ab4b37b&units=metric');
weather=JSON.parse(data.responseText);
console.log(weather.main.temp);
if(data!="undefined"){
$('#temp').textContent = weather.main.temp;
}
});
```

So I am working on a chromeExtension and am using Open weather to get the city's weather. 
The problem start when i assign value of data I guess using getJSON  .
I get this error. : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I read somewhere that this means my data variable is undefined here. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous; it doesn't return a value as a result of the function call as you have attempted.  Instead, provide a callback function to process the returned data.  Lastly, the JSON is already parsed into an object for you.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=c5959a33372923c74fccc1d07ab4b37b&units=metric', function (weather) {
    console.log(weather.main.temp);
});
```